# Variable's value in mode-line?

Tags: mode-line

I have this function that sets the `isearch-filter-predicate` variable to a predicate (function) from a list of predicates:

```el
(defun set-isearch-filter-predicate ()
  (interactive)

  (unless (boundp 'IFP-default)
    (setq IFP-default isearch-filter-predicate))

  (let* ((INIT (symbol-name IFP-default))
     (PREDICATES '(
               "predicate1"
               "predicate2"
               "predicate3"
               ))
     (IFP_STRING (read-string "Choose predicate: " INIT nil PREDICATES))
     (IFP (intern-soft IFP_STRING)))

    (setq isearch-filter-predicate IFP)))
```

I'd like to view the "name" (e.g. "predicate1") of the predicate I've setted in the `mode-line`. Is it possible without define specific minor-modes?

I'd like also to know how to use symbols instead of strings (e.g. predicate1 instead of "predicate1" in my code, but it's not vital (I tried `read-command` instead of `read-string` but it doesn't work).

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. Please move your question about the 4th arg to `read-string` to another question. Thx.

Comment: Anyway, wrt your question about using symbols as candidates for a read function: use `completing-read`. You cannot use a list of symbols as the `DEFAULT-VALUE` argument (to `read-string`, `read-command`, `completing-read`, or other functions), but you can use it as the `COLLECTION` arg to `completing-read`.

Comment: You can of course apply `symbol-name` to each predicate symbol, and use the result as a `DEFAULT-VALUE` arg in `read-string` or whatever - e.g. `mapcar` `symbol-name` over your list of predicate symbols. But `completing-read` is what you want to use, in general - allow the user completion.

Comment: @Drew, thank you for the hints. Do you still suggest to move the second question in a separate one?

Comment: That's for you to decide. If you think it would help other users, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why do you not want to define a minor mode here?  It's as simple as this - in this case I put a character into the mode line, in `global-mode-string`, but you can adapt the code.

```el
    (defvar mlc-char-in-mode-line-mode-initialized nil
      "Non-nil if `mlc-char-in-mode-line-mode' has been called.")

    (define-minor-mode mlc-char-in-mode-line-mode
      "Show char after point in mode line, at start of `global-mode-string'."
      nil nil nil :group 'Modeline
      (unless mlc-char-in-mode-line-mode-initialized
        (setq mlc-char-in-mode-line-mode-initialized  t)
        (setq global-mode-string
              (cond ((consp global-mode-string)
                     (add-to-list 'global-mode-string mlc-mode-line-char-format))
                    ((not global-mode-string)
                     (list mlc-mode-line-char-format))
                    ((stringp global-mode-string)
                     (list mlc-mode-line-char-format global-mode-string))))))
```

`mlc-mode-line-char-format` does essentially this:

```el
    (let* ((ch   (following-char))
           (str  (format (if (= ?% ch) "[%%%c=%06x] " "[%c=%06x] ") ch ch)))
      str)
```

2. More generally, you can use one of the mode-line variables described in the Elisp manual, node [Mode Line Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Variables.html).  See node [Mode Line Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html) for  an understanding of how data you put in the mode line needs to be formatted.

   In particular, you can show the value of a symbol in the mode line just by inserting the symbol there. From [Mode Line Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html):

> A **symbol** as a mode line construct stands for its value.  The value
>        of `SYMBOL` is used as a mode line construct, in place of `SYMBOL`.
>        However, the symbols `t` and `nil` are ignored, as is any symbol
>        whose value is void.
>
> There is one exception: if the value of `SYMBOL` is a *string*, it is
>        displayed verbatim: the `%`-constructs are not recognized.
>
> Unless `SYMBOL` is marked as risky (i.e., it has a non-`nil`
>        `risky-local-variable` property), all text properties specified in
>        `SYMBOL`’s value are ignored.  This includes the text properties of
>        strings in `SYMBOL`’s value, as well as all `:eval` and `:propertize`
>        forms in it.  (The reason for this is security: non-risky variables
>        could be set automatically from file variables without prompting
>        the user.)